# Failed to load resource: 404 Not Found in undefined path

Tags: compiler-errors, http-status-code-404, google-chrome-devtools

I have received this strange error from my Chrome Console. It doesn't provide me with any path for 404 Not Found but it was just an undefined path... I don't even know in which place I've got errors and it even replied me with 32 errors...

Does anyone have any idea on this? Thank you for your time for reading my question.

[image: What I saw from Google Chrome Console]

Comment: Hello, we have the same error, can you post the solution if you found it.
Thank you.